# ASCII Text Browser Vs. cURL

Tags: linux, bash, unix, curl, browser

I hit this url : http://artii.herokuapp.com/make?text=abc+art&font=smisome1

I see this

[image]

Then when I `curl` exact same URL

`curl http://artii.herokuapp.com/make?text=abc+art&font=smisome1`

I got this

[image]

‍♂️

Does anyone know why this is happening ?

Is there a specific flag in the curl I should pass to make it return the same result as broswer ?

How do I get my Terminal to display the same ASCII text format as the browser ?

Comment: I didn't vote down. `[1] 7219` gives an important clue.

Comment: I apologize that I missed that. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: No downvote from me, but this is off-topic, as it's not about programming. Try superuser.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ampersand in the URL is breaking up the command.

If you escape the ampersand you should achieved the desired return.

E.G.
    curl http://artii.herokuapp.com/make?text=abc+art\&font=smisome1

Comment: ... or use single quotes: `curl 'http://artii.herokuapp.com/make?text=abc+art&font=smisome1'`

Answer (score 1):

In browser you using `&font=smisome1` (look on end of your url) in terminal you don't using this font because of `&`.

Maybe [this](https://gist.github.com/LunaCodeGirl/6707775) help you. Sorry for not professional answer.